# Installing from rpm gives weird dependency error

Tags: fedora, mysql, rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to install mysql from rpm file and this is what is get.

```
libaio.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libcrypt.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libdl.so.2 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libm.so.6 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libpthread.so.0 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
librt.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libstdc++.so.6 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.i686
```

Comment: Why not install MySql from the usual repo so that all the dependencies will be found and installed?

Comment: I require a particular version 5.6.12 and i took it from mysql.com. Plus when i installed mysql on amazon instances, it just installs, but now it shows errors in fedora.

Comment: Looks like you were trying to install version 5.6.14.  If you are running Fedora 18 or 19 and the latest version of MySQL is okay (version 5.6.15 today), why not install following [MySQL's "install from our repo" instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html)?

Answer (score 0):

From [LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-%60glibcxx_3-4-11%27-not-found-943114/) forum:

> The easy way is to make a backup of your /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8, and delete the link libstdc++.so.6 , and use a replacement that works  with your glibc : will usually be libstdc++.so.6.0.13 from the package libstdc++6_4.4.5-8_i386.deb ( 32bits ) http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool...4.5-8_i386.deb 64bits http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool....5-8_amd64.deb
>
> Unpack with : ar -x .deb && tar xvf data.tar.gz, ... and copy libstdc++.so.6.0.13 to /usr/lib/, and : # ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.13 libstdc++.so.6

<sub>Reference: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libstdc++6</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing this? rpm -ivh? you can install using "yum install filename.rpm". So yum will try to resolve dependencies on its own.

on the other hand, this link for 5.6.15 could prove useful
http://tecadmin.net/step-to-install-mysql-5-6-12-on-centos-6-and-rhel-6/#